# SQL SELECT INNER JOIN WHERE OFFSET

Tags: php, sql, select, request, where-clause

I am trying to code a search bar on my website, bu when I add the WHERE .. LIKE I get an error.

```
$SELECT *
FROM articles
INNER JOIN fournisseur ON fournisseur.fournisseur_id = articles._fournisseur_id
ORDER BY ".$order." LIMIT ".$limit." OFFSET ".$debut."
WHERE article_designation LIKE ".$recherche."
```

And here is the error message :

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE article_designation LIKE aspirateur' at line 1' in

The request is perfectly working without the `WHERE`.  What's wrong with the query?

Comment: where goes before limit, and usually order

Comment: The correct order is `SELECT ... FROM ... INNER JOIN ... WHERE ... ORDER BY ... LIMIT`

Comment: ... and you need a space just before the keyword WHERE

Comment: @Siyual is right the where is in the wrong place not ... must be not after order by but before  ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need your `WHERE` clause to come before `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT`

Comment: Thank you for your help  :)